# Setup.exe doesn't run

Tags: windows-7, setup

I have a setup file that just refuses to run.. There is no error message or anything.  I double click the exe file and nothing happens. I went to the Event Viewer and found an Application Error with these details for the file i am trying to run:

```
Faulting application name: Setup.exe_Installer, version: 6.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5278248e
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1116
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c41f
Faulting process id: 0x1640
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf41386f5bd732
Faulting application path: G:\Setup.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: ad4fcb5a-ad2b-11e3-86d9-082e5f74cade
```

The Event ID is 1000. What is wrong? I am able to run other .exe files normally.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the dll I would contact the author of the setup for help

Comment: The same setup works for other people and doesn't for a few. What more info could i provide to help figure the issue?

Comment: There is something different about your installation you provided information required to narrow it down.

Comment: 0xe0434352 means CLR exception for almost all .Net exceptions so it's not possible to say what was the exact problem at this stage. A process dump captured by a debugging tool such as "ProcDump" and "WinDBG" helps the author to investigate your issue.